# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert Entity @73012e07 of type class Entity to class java.util.TreeMap

Tags: hibernate, jsf

I have an Entity Java Class that I use in Hibernate. I have another Java class, that  has a method that gets the ID of a row in a data table of the JSF page. 
It takes the ID of that row, so that I can edit this specific row in a datatable. I have used a TreeMap to get this ID.

But when I click on the button Edit, I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert cms.Inventory@73012e07 of type class cms.Inventory to class java.util.TreeMap

Note that cms is the package, and Inventory is the Entity java class which consists of getters and setters.

The `ManagedBean InventoryManager.java` has the method:

```
public String Edit_Inventory(TreeMap Rgs) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

// codes to get the id of a row (works fine)
// then populate the details of this id to another JSF form.
```

Can someone help me to find the cause of this exception please ? Let me know to provide additional codes.

Note that I am using Hibernate fro CRUD functionality.

Comment: Please include stack trace (in code formatted block) to exclude ambiguity in the cause.

Comment: First I recommend to use java naming standards http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html, secondly I guess when you call Edit_Inventory method you send Inventory object instead of a TreeMap. But it is hard to give an answer since I dont know how you call this method